# Is it better to have many columns or a single column bit string for many checkboxes

Tags: mysql, database-performance, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have the following scenario:

A form with many checkboxes, around 100.

I have 2 ideas on how to save them in database:

#### 1. Multicolumn

I create a table looking like this:

```
id | box1 | box2 | ... | box100 | updated| created

id: int
box1: bit(1)


SELECT * FROM table WHERE box1 = 1 AND box22 = 1 ...
```

#### 2. Single data column

Table is simply:

```
id | data | updated | created

data: varchar(100)

SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '_______1___ ... ____1____1'
```

where data looks like `0001100101010......01` each character representing if value was checked or not.

Considering that the table will have 200k+ rows, which is a more scalable solution?

#### 3. Single data column of type JSON

I have no good information about this yet.

Comment: A better arrangement would be to have a table per box, which only keeps the keys for your main table, when the boxes are ticked.

Comment: Neither scheme that you have suggested scales well.

Comment: And have 100 tables? How is that better?

Comment: A table per checkbox? Are you nuts?

Comment: If I want to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE box1 = 1 AND ...` 30 boxes, how many joins is that?

Comment: If your solution causes you to have to monkey with your DB schema (column/table adding/removing) every time you add/remove a control your schema is bad. If your schema causes you to have to parse a column to get a value out (and breaks when you add more controls) it's a bad schema. `id | form_submission_id | control_id | value` would make a lot more sense here. Your form submission with 100 checkboxes/controls would generate 100 records. Scalable. Indexable. Done.

Comment: Tables that aren't carrying either something that requires a calculation to extract meaningful values, and which can be extended if you add an extra box. It also allows you to drop individual boxes if they are no longer used.

This is a basic normalisation of your data.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I couldn't disagree more with your solution. It sounds like a nightmare to maintain and to query.

Comment: @JNevill you mean similar to wordpress `postmeta` table, like `id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value` ?

Comment: @JNevill But considering those 200k+ rows I would have in one table, now in this new table I will have 200k * 100 = 20M rows....

Comment: I suppose it's like that. Imagine your application changing. Adding more controls or removing them. Pick a schema that allows you to add/remove RECORDS. Not one that causes you to add remove objects like Columns/Tables/Views to adjust. Databases should grow in records. It's what they are made for. You can index records you can submit basic `UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE` statements to deal with them. The less DDL statements you have to submit, the better. I mean... how do you properly index 100 checkbox columns to make your app fast? You don't. How do you index 100 tables to hold checkboxes? yuck.

Comment: 20M. That's not big data. No worries there. Databases are meant to have lots of records. That's why there is indexing, partitioning, stats collections, shared-nothing architectures, and all the other DB tuning that exists. The tuning tools at your disposal are built to deal with LOTS of records, not LOTS of columns or LOTS of tables.

Comment: @JNevill Ok, what about between idea 1 and 2, do you have any idea which would be better?

Comment: That's like having to choose between the titanic and the lusitania for historical ships that I would want to be on. The columns one... I suppose. Only because with the binary/bitmask single column solution, if you ever add a new column then the position of your characters in the string (or bits in the bitmask) either have to be updated (yuck) or compensated for in your code. Which means you'll have a historical patch every time your application changes. Plus you have to have code to deal with keeping track of the position of the char/bit in the string/bitmask.

Comment: Furthmore... the single column solution is a MONSTER on your database's 1) CPU - Anytime you want to pull a form where a checkbox is a certain value your DB has to parse EVERY record to find where that one bit is flipped. 2) I/O - To pull forms where a checkbox is true/false your DB has to pull EVERY record out of storage causing a very large intermediate result set that is then sent to the CPU to parse out that value. Your queries are going to be slow slow slow and your box, if it had a consciousness, would hate you.

Comment: The multi-column solution (besides the scalability issue which is a non-starter by itself) would be a bear to index for fast reads. You either end up indexing every column and potentially combinations of commonly queried controls or you suffer slow queries. Every index can be thought of as its own table of data. So now to keep your record count small you actually just ballooned it to store indexes just to get a performant query. There's really a lot working against both of these.

Comment: @JNevill I see, I decided to go with your solution. One more question though. Is it worth putting columns `last_updated` and `created` on the `meta_key - meta_value` table?

Comment: Max of 16 columns per index; max of 64 secondary indexes in InnoDB.  This says that most (all?) options cannot really use indexing for arbitrary subsets of 100 thingies.  Partitioning is also useless.

Comment: Does anyone ever really use `last_updated` or `created` columns??  I see them as not-useful columns being added by 3rd party packages.  Toss them unless you _really_ have a need for them.

Comment: Suggest this change to JNevill's solution:  Don't store all 100 rows; store only the ones that where checked.  Also get rid of the `value` column.  This cuts down significantly on the bulk though it makes some queries a bit messier.

Comment: @JNevill - you should present an Answer with Option 6, and collect the details of how a single table with a single index, etc, can answer the Question.  My '5' and your '6' are probable the best candidates.  It's hard to compare when '6' is buried in a bunch of Comments.

Answer (score 2):

Or...

**4. A few `SETs`**

**5. A few `INTs`**

- These are much more compact:  about 8 checkboxes per byte.
- They are a bit messy to set/test.
- Since they are limited to 64 bits, you would need more than one `SET` or `INT`.  I recommend grouping the bits is some logical way, based on the app.
- Be aware of `FIND_IN_SET()`.
- Be aware of `(1 << $n)` for creating the value `2^n`.
- Be aware of `|` and `&` Operators.

Which of the 5 is best?  That depends on the queries you need to run -- for searching (if necessary?), for inserting, for updating (if necessary?), and for selecting.

An example:  For `INTs` , `WHERE (bits & 0x2C08) = 0x2C08` would simultaneously check for 4 flags being 'ON'.  That constant could either be constructed in app code, or `((1<<13) | (1<<11) | (1<<10) | (1<<3))` for bits 3,10,11,13.  Meanwhile, the other flags are ignored.  If you need them to be 'OFF', the test would be `WHERE bits ^ 0x2C08 = 0`.  If either of these kind of test is your main activity, then Choice 5 is probably the best for both performance and space, though it is somewhat cryptic to read.

When adding another option, `SET` requires an `ALTER TABLE`.  `INT` *usually* has some spare bits (`TINYINT UNSIGNED` has 8 bits, ... `BIGINT UNSIGNED` has 64).  So, about one time in 8, you would need an `ALTER` to get a bigger INT or add another INT.  Deleting an option:  suggest just abandoning that SET element or bit of INT.

Comment: the heaviest queries will be selecting (exporting) based on conditions.

Comment: @Lemures - and I commented on adding another checkbox.